# Program Pandas Cross Tab in a Loop

Tags: pandas, jupyter, crosstab

I'm trying to publish a series of cross tabs in pandas, in the context of a jupyter notebook, like so:

```
def crosstab_all(dataset,attributelist):
    for k in attributelist:
        print('k',k)
        pd.crosstab(dataset[k],dataset["successfulmatch"], normalize=True, margins=True, margins_name="Total")

attributelist=["has_closing_date","has_address",'has_price','has_listing_date','has_contract_dates','has_tsp','has_susan','has_sell_side','has_buy_side','has_both_sides','has_beth','has_agent','has_admin','has_closing_tsp','has_key_stages']

crosstab_all(dataset,attributelist)
```

I find that if I just do:

```
k="has_closing_date"
pd.crosstab(dataset[k],dataset["successfulmatch"], normalize=True, margins=True, margins_name="Total")
```

... it will work.  The issue seems to be running successive crosstab function calls.  So for example having two crosstab commands in immediate succession will fail.  I suspect that the problem is not the crosstab command as such but rather some extra step I need to spawn multiple jupyter windows.

Anyway, I appreciate any suggestions as to how to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found something that works.  This solution doesn't generate separate windows, and you lose some formatting, but I learned that crosstab returns a dataframe, so you can just print that, like so:

```
def crosstab_all(dataset,attributelist):
    for k in attributelist:
        xdf=pd.crosstab(dataset[k],dataset["successfulmatch"], normalize=True, margins=True, margins_name="Total")
        print('xdf',xdf)
        print('') # for spacing

attributelist=["has_closing_date","has_address",'has_price','has_listing_date','has_contract_dates','has_tsp','has_susan','has_sell_side','has_buy_side','has_both_sides','has_beth','has_agent','has_admin','has_closing_tsp','has_key_stages']

crosstab_all(dataset,attributelist) # dataset is a dataframe
```

This will return you an unformatted xtab with each pass of the loop.